# How do I screencast video output for android activity ?(no root)

Tags: android

I need to record screen video in mp4 format for android. How do i screencast video output in android activity?
Like [Screencast Video Recorder Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree&hl=tr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super easy with Android 4.4 :
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording

You'll get smooth, high definition videos.

Comment: Thanks for helping Stephane. I need to implement in my applications.